# I need to complete my If's Formula and need to figure out how to cap the amount at 3000

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the Formula so Far - =ifs(D1126<=0,600,D1126<= 20000,1200,D1126>20000, D1126*0.06)I need max the amount to be 3000

=ifs(D1118<=0,600,D1118<= 20000,1200,D1118<=50000, D1118*0.06,D1118>50000,3000)but now its overwriting my 2000 cap on anything below 20000.

Comment: Make sure your number of zeros is right... I don't see anything with a 2000 cap... only a 20000. Maybe you typed something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what you're doing in your IFS statement, but if you want the MAXIMUM value returned from the cell to be 3,000, then you could probably use your formula combined with [MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en) function (which may seem counterintuitive since you want a MAXIMUM of of 3,000). Something like this:

```
=min(ifs(A1<=0,600,A1<= 20000,1200,A1>20000, A1*0.06),3000)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a shot at it. So here is what I am trying to accomplish - 
if debt amount(D2)  = 0 then fee (c2) = 850 ; if debt amount(D2) = 20K or less then fee (c2)=1200; If debt amount(D2)  =20001 or more then fee (c2)= D2*.06 - But the highest fee would be 3K so Im getting stuck on the 3K max fee part